# Unable to Reference a S3 file in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-lambda-layers

I have a S3 file called python.zip already uploaded which Im trying to reference to add it in Lambda Layer.
I am using aws_s3_object data/resource in Terraform but it is erroring out no matter what I do.

** Error: Invalid data source

on main.tf line 12, in data "aws_S3_object" "layer_object":
12: data "aws_S3_object" "layer_object" {

The provider provider.aws does not support data source "aws_S3_object". **

Below Terraform code that I am using.

```
terraform {
  backend s3 {
    key             = "InstanceCleanup.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table  = "terraform-state-locking"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_S3_object" "layer_object" {
  bucket = "agent-buildup-806471337920"
  key    = "python.zip"
 }

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "my_layer" {
  filename            = "python.zip"
  layer_name          = "Requests-2.31.0"
  description         = "Requests module for python 3.8 compatibilty"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.8"]
  s3_bucket           = data.aws_S3_object.layer_object.bucket
  s3_key              = data.aws_S3_object.layer_object.key
}

## Lambda Function ##
resource "aws_lambda_function" "Instance_Cleanup" {
  function_name = "Instance-Cleanup-function"
  handler       = "Instance-Cleanup.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
  filename      = "Instance-Cleanup.zip"
  timeout       = 10
  role          = aws_iam_role.Lambda_role.arn

  layers = [aws_lambda_layer_version.my_layer.arn]
  
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("Instance-Cleanup.zip")

  environment {
    variables = {
      pool_ids        = join(",", var.pool_ids)
      instance_names  = join(",", var.instance_names)
    }
  }

}
```

Help me guys !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_object) name is `aws_s3_object`, with a lower case `s3`, not `aws_S3_object`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, this had me for 1 hour.